# How to make an absolute positioned div fill the entire document area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to have an absolute `div` that is a child of only `body` fill the entire document area (window + any scroll area)
 -- width: 100% only fills the viewable screen

I prefer a CSS only solution but pure javascript is ok. I tried without success setting:

```
opaque.style.minHeight = Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

I made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/dsxvre7t/) of the code below. If you scroll down the output, you will see that the opaque div stops at whatever height the output window was when it was rendered.

In case you are wondering... it is to make an opaque overlay of all content in the div behind it (think slideshow). My only other solution is to disable scrolling, but this is problematic.

Thanks for any help.

```
<div class="page-container"></div>    
<div id="opaque"></div>

body {
    width:100%;
}
.page-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width:978px; 
    width: 100%;
    min-height:2500px; 
    margin:0 auto -50px auto; 
    border:solid #999;
    border-width:2px;
    background: lightblue;
}

#opaque {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background: grey;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can use

```
#opaque {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

remove `width:100%` from body due to creates horizontal scrollbar

Depending on use case it is often common to add class to body when using such an overlay that sets body overflow to hidden

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dsxvre7t/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Your answer also does the trick. Thanks. It produces identical results to the one from sahbeewah. Would either one be preferable?

Comment: To be honest I have been doing this for many years and just learned a new trick from that other answer. Often there are numerous ways to achieve same objective

Comment: I just read that `fixed` positioning is "relative to the viewport" so it seems that it was made for this. It also explains why I've never needed it in the past. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can put a `position: relative` on your body so that the body will be used as a reference point by the child element in terms of height (as opposed to the `document` object).

Comment: Wow. That really was simple. More amazing is that it didn't mess up the rest of my website. Can you comment on the difference between your solution and the one from charlietfl? They both work. Would either be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript to set one elements height equal to anothers

```
var o = document.getElementById('opaque');
var p = document.querySelector('.page-container');

o.style.height = window.getComputedStyle(p).getPropertyValue("height");
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/dsxvre7t/2/)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the `getComputedStyle` method. I will go with a pure css solution for this one, but this will help in the future.